# Transaction taking too long (Don't mint)

Tags: web3.js, rpc, transaction

I'm having a problem in transaction mint time.

Sometimes I send a transaction and it never mints. The transactionHash is created and nothing happens. My code is:

```
const lastBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

const transaction = new Transaction({
  recentBlockhash: lastBlockHash.blockhash,
  feePayer: input.feePayer
});

//add instructions...

transaction.sign(...signers)
const transactionId = await connection.sendRawTransaction(transaction.serialize(), {
   skipPreflight: false
})
```

After this I check for its status and value always comes null. It neither appears on solscan as the transaction never existed. It happens often. What's the problem here? What can I do to send always a valid transaction?

Comment: Can you show us the full code, also make sure to choose the right network in the explorer.